# How to create side by side textareas?

Tags: html, css, alignment

I want to create 4 textareas in one row, each with its own title, this is the illustration of what I wanna do:

[image]

I've tried this:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<div style="float:left;">
    <p>
        title1<br />
        <textarea cols="15" rows="15">
        textarea1
        </textarea><br />
        title2<br />
        <textarea cols="15" rows="15">textarea2</textarea>
    </p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Instead it creates 2 textareas in 2 rows, I want 4 textareas in one row and a title centered on each textarea. How do I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

to make it more perfect add a common class to each of the div and apply css like below:

**Html**

```
<div class="inline-div">
    <p align="center">Title 1</p>
    <textarea cols="15" rows="15" class="inline-txtarea"></textarea>
</div>
<div class="inline-div">
<p align="center">Title 2</p>
    <textarea cols="15" rows="15" class="inline-txtarea"></textarea>
</div>
<div class="inline-div">
    <p align="center">Title 3</p>
    <textarea cols="15" rows="15" class="inline-txtarea"></textarea>
</div>
<div class="inline-div">
    <p align="center">Title 4</p>
    <textarea cols="15" rows="15" class="inline-txtarea"></textarea>
</div>
```

**Css**

```
.inline-div {
    display:inline-block;
}
.inline-txtarea {
    resize: none;
    border : 2px solid red;
    height:125px;
}
```

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vnrkgwdm/)

Answer (score 4):

This a cleaner solution imho http://jsfiddle.net/yoge56eg/

the idea behind this css its to wrap all the content inside of a `<div>` class in this case the class is named `.textAreaColumn` (the . before the name works to define class while if you use # you will be defining an ID which mean its gonna be use only by one element in the html. in this case we are using a class `.` with the dot cause we want to be able to use it in many cases, if we want another 4 grids in a different place in the same page, we can have them.

then from them we start getting deep in the structure of the CSS, if you see we have a `.textAreaColumn div` which mean that the  will modify all  children. And .textAreaColumn div span` mean that will target the div with class .textAreaColumn that have a div and that div contain a span. Look at the html and you will see how that make sense.

and inside of this declaration are only properties the modify these elements.

**CSS**

```
.textAreaColumn{
    width:100%;    
}
.textAreaColumn div{
    float:left;
    width:25%;
    padding:10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.textAreaColumn div span{
    display:block;
    text-align:center;
}

.textAreaColumn div textarea{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width:100%;
    border:3px solid red;
    min-height:150px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="textAreaColumn">
    <div>
        <span>Title 1</span>
        <textarea>Content goes here</textarea>
    </div>
    <div>
        <span>Title 2</span>
        <textarea>Content goes here</textarea>
    </div>
    <div>
        <span>Title 3</span>
        <textarea>Content goes here</textarea>
    </div>
    <div>
        <span>Title 4</span>
        <textarea>Content goes here</textarea>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

---- EDIT ----

Exactly as you ask for:

http://jsfiddle.net/yoge56eg/3/

[image]

-- EDIT Update ---

http://jsfiddle.net/yoge56eg/4/ with `<span>` with text align center

Comment: is there a way to make all the titles aligned on center of each textarea ? I tried this on your code but didn't work `<font align="center">Title 1</font>`

Comment: don't use font align="center" that deprecate it! I will update my answer

Comment: That's really nice @ncubica can you explain me how this works? css I Mean, i'm just a beginer at the css

Answer (score 1):

Just get rid of the unnecessary html elements and and put each block (Title + textarea) in separate `div` (*for example*), then change its' layout to `inline-block` and center each block with CSS.

*HTML :*

```
<div >
    <div>
       <p>Title 1</p>
       <textarea cols="15" rows="15">textarea1</textarea>
    </div>
    <div>
       <p>Title 2</p>
       <textarea cols="15" rows="15">textarea2</textarea>
    </div>
    <div>
       <p>Title 3</p>
       <textarea cols="15" rows="15">textarea3</textarea>
    </div>
    <div>
       <p>Title 4</p>
       <textarea cols="15" rows="15">textarea4</textarea>
    </div>
</div>
```

*CSS :*

```
div { text-align: center; }
div > div { display: inline-block }
textarea {  resize: none;border : 2px solid red }
```

*Illustration :*

[image]

#### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uo1uLr5n/2/)

Comment: What about the titles ? I want 4 textareas in one row and a title centered on each textarea just like in the illustration I provided

Comment: @hillz, this is the clean & clear way with minimal code, to make it more perfect add a common class to each of the div and apply css (display:inline-block) accordingly.. (ex: <div class="inline-div">...</div>, css: .inline-div{display:inline-block;})

Answer (score 0):

A cleaner way to achieve this is to wrap all the titles together and the textareas together.

**Working Code Snippet:**

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

p:nth-child(1){
  display: table;
}

p span{
  display: table-cell;
  width: 31%;
}

p:nth-child(1){
  padding-left: 13%;
}

textarea{
  width: 23%;
  border: 2px solid red;
  resize: none;
}

textarea:nth-child(1){
  border: 4px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div style="float:left;">
  <p>
    <span>title1</span>
    <span>title2</span>
    <span>title3</span>
    <span>title4</span>
  </p>
  <p>
    <textarea>
      textarea1
    </textarea>
    <textarea>
      textarea2
    </textarea>
    <textarea>
      textarea3
    </textarea>
    <textarea>
      textarea4
    </textarea>
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

the solution is in jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Lhk1muwf/
Html should be

```
<div id="main">
<div class="sub"><h2>Title 1</h2>
    <textarea cols="15" rows="15">textarea 1</textarea>
</div>
<div class="sub"><h2>Title 2</h2>
    <textarea cols="15" rows="15">textarea 2</textarea>
</div>
<div class="sub"><h2>Title 3</h2>
    <textarea cols="15" rows="15">textarea 3</textarea>
</div>
<div class="sub"><h2>Title 4</h2>
    <textarea cols="15" rows="15">textarea 4</textarea>
</div>
```

css should be

```
#main 
{
    text-align:center;
    display:inline-block;
}
#main .sub
{
    float:left;
    margin-right:10px;
}
```

Comment: you are writing 4 time the same code `class="sub"` and also assigning and `id` as anchor of the style, if you want to reuse this code block will not be possible, and if you have 100 textareas inside of wrapper, you will repeat unnecessarily class="sub" 100 times. just a little comment

Answer (score 0):

To put textareas side by side you can also use a table with optional CSS:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td, th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 8px;
}
textarea {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
    width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #ddeef8;
  font-size: 16px;
  resize: none;

}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #aadddd;
  
}
</style>
</head>
<body>



<table>
  <tr>
    <th>title1</th>
    <th>title1</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><textarea cols="15" rows="15">textarea1</textarea></td>
    <td><textarea cols="15" rows="15">textarea2</textarea></td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html
```